# Why doesn't StartWorkflow() start my workflow in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to programatically start a SharePoint 2013 workflow.  The workflow takes five parameters, puts them in an email body and e-mails them to me.  When I go to the SharePoint website I can start this workflow manually, so I know the workflow is correct.  When I try to use the SharePoint API's to start the workflow, I get no errors, I get an empty Guid back, and the workflow does not run.

```
public Guid Add(Project project)
{
    var result = Guid.Empty;
    var siteUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharePoint.Site"]);
    var workflowName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharePoint.WorkflowName"];
    using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(siteUri, null))
    {
        var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext, clientContext.Web);
        var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
        var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptions();
        clientContext.Load(subscriptions, subs => subs.Where(sub => sub.Name == workflowName));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            var instanceService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
            var initiationData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"pProjectName", project.Name},
                {"pDivision", _divisionData.GetDivisionName(project.DivisionId ?? Guid.Empty) },
                {"pOperatingGroup", "****TODO: Operating Group****"},
                {"pClientName", _clientData.GetClientName(project.ClientId ?? Guid.Empty) },
                {"pSiteUrl", "****TODO: Site URL****" }
            };
            var startResult = instanceService.StartWorkflow(subscription, initiationData);
            result = startResult.Value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you check the Windows Event Log for relevant entries?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, no relevant Events.

Answer (score 0):

```
string subscriptionID = "WFListSubscriptionID of your wf";//it is a guid
int itemID = "Item.ID, Id of a item that you start wf for";
Guid workflowSubscriptionIdGuid = new Guid(subscriptionID);
var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(item.Web);
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var workflowSubscription = workflowSubscriptionService.GetSubscription(workflowSubscriptionIdGuid);
var inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService().StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, itemID, inputParameters);
```